# replacing specific columns values in 2d array numpy

Tags: python, numpy

how to replace 4th and 5th column values in utl by new_values array and keep the remaining columns as it is

```
utl = np.array([[  3.  , 134.4 , 17.  ,   135.05 ,    22. ,   135.25 ,   0.04     ],
                [ 12.  , 134.3 , 17.  ,   135.05 ,    22. ,  135.8  ,    0.15     ]])

new_values=np.array([[ 27.,   135.45],
                     [ 27.,   136.55]])
```

i tried this but it does not work

```
# utl[:,[4,5]] = new_values 
# utl[:,4] = new_values[:,0]
```

output must be

```
                                      #values changed 
[[  3.  , 134.4 , 17.  ,   135.05 ,  |  27. ,  135.45  |,   0.04     ],
 [ 12.  , 134.3 , 17.  ,   135.05 ,  |  27. ,  136.55  |,    0.15     ]])
```

Comment: `utl[:, [4, 5]] = new_values`

Comment: @Ch3steR By editing in the commas, you have hidden the original problem that OP had with the code

Comment: @BenGrossmann - Would have caused a SyntaxError.The part that "doesn't work" is in the comments

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That is what the question as originally written seems to imply. However, there's nothing wrong with the commented lines, so something else must be wrong

Comment: Please include the unexpected result or error message. In its current form, this question will be closed as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 0):

this works fine, as expected:

```
utl[:, [4,5]] = new_values
```

output:

```
array([[  3.  , 134.4 ,  17.  , 135.05,  27.  , 135.45,   0.04],
       [ 12.  , 134.3 ,  17.  , 135.05,  27.  , 136.55,   0.15]])
```